# Does Dim's position matter?

Tags: vbscript, scope

I noticed that I can `Dim` a variable *after* using it or (in other words) use it before `Dim`ing, even when using `Option Explicit`. Try this:

```
Option Explicit

x = "before Dim"
WScript.Echo x

Dim x
x = "after Dim"
WScript.Echo x
```

The same works fine in a `Sub` or `Function`.

Apparently, it does not matter on which line the `Dim` is, as long as it is in the same scope (current `Function`/`Sub` or global). I wonder why this works. Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz.aspx#Anchor_2) explicitly says (emphasis mine):

> The lifetime of a script-level variable extends from **the time it is
>   declared** until the time the script is finished running.

I read this like: first `Dim` then use. But I was wrong...? Why is this?!

VB6 does *not* allow this:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic
---------------------------
Compile error:

Variable not defined
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

Comment: The extract is the contract and what you must follow because we don't take dependencies on implementation. For your general info declares are hoisted to the top. See http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/18/159378.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extract is the contract and what you must follow because we don't take dependencies on implementation. For your general info declares are hoisted to the top. [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) [wrote](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/06/18/159378.aspx):

> Why can we use a variable before declaring it in VBScript?
>   ...
>
> What's up with that? Well, let me ask you this -- if you think that
>   looks weird, why do you think this looks normal?
>
> ```
> Dim s
> s = Foo(123)
> Function Foo(x)
>   Foo = x + 345
> End Function
> ```
>
> There the function is being used before it is declared, but that
>   doesn't bug you, right?
>
> Similarly, variables can be used before they are declared. The
>   behaviour is by design. Variable declarations and functions are
>   logically "hoisted" to the top of their scope in both VBScript and
>   JScript.

**EDIT**

VBScript follows VBA rules as far as possible. This is the implementation doc for implementing VBA. For VBS/VBA programmers it is for info only.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx

Comment: That link is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: That last document is an interesting read, but all it says about this issue is *The variable is accessible within the enclosing project* IIUC.

Comment: I saw that doc on my desktop and thought if you are interested in generally how it works then it gives insight.